# NSApp.sendAction() only works after some time

Tags: macos, cocoa, nssplitview, responder-chain

I want a ViewController (**ContainerVC**) to react on clicks on child custom views (**ChildView**).

In **ChildView** I override `mouseDown(_:)` to handle the click. In this method I try to call the **ContainerVC** target via `NSApp.sendAction(#selector(ContainerVC.childViewClicked(_:)), to: nil, from: self)`.

For some reason the `sendAction` method fails (i.e. returns false) at first. Also `NSApp.target(forAction: #selector(ContainerVC.childViewClicked(_:))` is nil.

After a some time (usually after me wildly clicking on the custom views for some time), the target gets resolved and everything works fine and ContainerVC.childViewClicked(_:) is called.

I couldn't find a systematic pattern after what time/how many clicks the target gets resolved (other than the intensity of me shouting at my mac).

Interestingly it works fine, when I add **ContainerVC** to a window via `let window = NSWindow(contentViewController: ContainerVC())`.

The strange behaviour described above occurs when I add **ContainerVC** to a split view:

```
self.addSplitViewItem(NSSplitViewItem(viewController: ContainerVC())
```

I checked the responder chain of **CustomView**. **ContainerVC** appears in the chain as expected. There are no other classes in the chain that implement **childViewClicked(_:)**.

I'd appreciate if someone could enlighten me about the inner workings of NSApp.sendAction(_:) and why the target is nil at first.

Are there additional steps necessary when adding a ViewController to a SplitView to wire up things properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation of `sendAction(_:to:from:)`:

> If aTarget is nil, sharedApplication looks for an object that can respond to the message—that is, an object that implements a method matching anAction. It begins with the first responder of the key window.

When ChildView isn't the first responder, `sendAction(_:to:from:)` doesn't work. Use

```
func `try`(toPerform action: Selector, with object: Any?) -> Bool
```

for example

```
self.`try`(toPerform: #selector(ContainerVC.childViewClicked(_:)), with: self)
```

which does what you want:

> If the receiver responds to anAction, it invokes the method with anObject as the argument and returns YES. If the receiver doesn’t respond, it sends this message to its next responder with the same selector and object.